# can get data out of http request

Tags: frontend, angular2-http

i have a problem receiving data to variable.

this works:

```
    this.http.get(some_url).subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log(JSON.parse(data['_body']))
    });
```

but if i try to get the value to a variable instead of printing it, it does not work:

```
    this.http.get(some_url).subscribe(
        data => {
            this.var = JSON.parse(data['_body'])
    });
```

i need your help, i tried everything.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be an angular 2 issue. Can you try the following steps to debug?

1. Check the console (F12) for any errors while making the GET call
2. Print *and* store the returned the data in the variable
3. Are there any lines above the variable assignment line that you have not posted?

I've created a plunker where you can see the variable assignment in action
https://embed.plnkr.co/MEHTZ92HgZhEbUZlBELQ/

the app.component.ts is as follows

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <p>Content: {{ content }}</p>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {

  content: string;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
   this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').subscribe(
        data => {
            this.content = data
    });
  }

}
```

And the result I get is

```
Content: Response with status: 200 OK for URL: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1
```

Of course, one shouldn't use the constructor for network calls and similar heavy stuff and should use [ngOnInit](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit) instead, but just for the sake of example I've made the call in the constructor